# not able to load the page when accessed directly for the first time in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have a weird issue here..

We have a courses directory inside the public folder where we are saving some assignments.

now when I try to directly hit www.example.com/courses it redirects to 500.shtml and it is not even hitting the controller

but when I try the same route again it works..

I don't understand why is it not working the first time and where to look for the issue..

Please Note :- I do not have shell access to the server and we are on laravel 5.0

our current .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
    <Files ~ "^\w+\.(gif|jpe?g|png|docx)$">
    order deny,allow
    allow from all
    </Files>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##


# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# This domain inherits the “PHP” package.
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php5_module>
   php_flag asp_tags Off
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 32M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 525600
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
```

Thank you for any assistance

Comment: if its redirecting you to 500.shtml, then there is `500` internal server error. you may try with `APP_DEBUG=true`, and find the exact place of error.

Comment: it does not give any error.. it just considers that as a 404